# Solving an Inhomogeneous Recurrence Relation for Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, recurrence

I am trying to solve a recurrence relation for the Fibonacci Sequence, but the problem is that it is not homogeneous.

The recurrence relation is as follows:

F(n) = F(n -1) + F(n -2) + Θ(n) for n > 1, and Θ(n) = c1n + c2 , where c1, c2 > 0

Initial conditions: F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1

I've tried to solve it by treating it as a homogeneous linear second-ordered recurrence with constant coefficients, but I'm not sure how to solve it when I have:

F(n) - F(n - 1) - F(n - 2) = c1n + c2

Instead of:

F(n) - F(n - 1) - F(n - 2) = 0

What is the best method for solving this type of recurrence relation?

Comment: I feel like this question does not belong to here, but I cant tell which site it should be moved into.

Comment: Maybe this? https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lower and upper bound using the following inequalities:

```
2F(n-2) + Theta(n) < T(n) < 2F(n-1) + Theta(n)
```

You can easily justify that the lower and upper bounds are in `Theta(n 2^n)`. Hence, `T(n) = Theta(n 2^n)`.

Comment: I am not sure that the OP's  Θ denotes an asymptotic expression.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ansatz `F1(n) = a*n + b` you get

```
F1(n) - F1(n-1) - F1(n-2) = -a*n + 3a - b = Θ(n) = c1*n + c2.
```

So we have `a = -c1` and `b = -3c1 - c2`, i.e.

```
F1(n) = -c1*n - 3c1 - c2
```

solves the given recursion *without* looking at the initial conditions. Combine this with the solution `F0` of the homogenous recursion (see [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression))

```
F0(n) = d1*q1^n + d2*q2^n
```

with `q1/2 = (1 +/- sqrt(5))/2` to get

```
F(n) = F0(n) + F1(n) = d1*q1^n + d2*q2^n - c1*n - 3c1 - c2 .
```

Now one can adjust the factors `d1`,`d2` to match the given inital conditions by solving this system of linear equations

```
F(0) = d1 + d2 - 3c1 - c2 = 0
F(1) = d1*q1 + d2*q2 - 4c1 - c2 = 1
```

for `d1`,`d2`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: @user10605996 see the added details. The rest should be straight forward.